# Count of most commonly occurring bigram in 1500 IDs without repeating the count within an ID

Tags: r, nlp, text-mining

I'm trying to count the most commonly occurring bigram in 1500 IDS (1 ID per row with 1 event) without counting the bigram more than 1x in each ID (row). For example, if I have the IDs below, I would only want 'work day' counted 1 x in each ID. The summary for the number of times 'work day' should show-up in my analysis should be 2. Once 'work day' gets counted in an ID I don't want it counted again.

```
ID Text
1  "The work day was horrible. On this particular work day, I made 5 mistakes....."
2  "This long work day was the best for me. I miss a long work day, because I get into a rhythm....."
```

This is my code. It gives the total counts for the 40 most frequently occurring bigrams as a histogram showing the 2 word bigram and the count. I'm not sure if it is counting the occurrence of a bigram more than 1x per ID as listed above, although I do believe it's just taking all 'Events' and counting however many times the 2 word bigram is occurring regardless of ID.

```
Sum1 %>% 
    unnest_tokens(word, "Event", token = "ngrams", n = 2) %>% 
    separate(word, c("word1", "word2"), sep = " ") %>% 
    filter(!word1 %in% stop_words$word) %>%
    filter(!word2 %in% stop_words$word) %>% 
    unite(word,word1, word2, sep = " ") %>% 
    count(word, sort = TRUE) %>% 
    slice(1:40) %>% 
    ggplot() + geom_bar(aes(x=reorder(word,n), y=n), stat = "identity", fill = "#de5833") +
    theme_minimal() +
    coord_flip()
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
    library(tidytext)
    library(dplyr)

    d <- data.frame(ID = 1:2,
                    txt = c('a particular word', 
                            'a particular word a phrase and a particular word')
                    )
```

```
## > d

      ID                                              txt
    1  1                                a particular word
    2  2 a particular word a phrase and a particular word
```

using base R `strsplit` and `Filter` to filter out stopwords right from the original text, finally `distinct` to retain unique bigrams per ID only:

```
d |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(txt = strsplit(txt, split = '\\s')[[1]] |> 
           Filter(f = \(x) !(x %in% get_stopwords()$word)) |>
           paste(collapse = ' ')
         ) |>
  unnest_tokens(input = txt, output = 'tokens',
                token = 'ngrams', n = 2) |>
  distinct(ID, tokens)
```

(`strsplit` returns a list whose single item, the word vector, has to be plucked with `[[1]]` before `Filter`ing)

output:

```
+ # A tibble: 4 x 2
# Rowwise: 
     ID tokens           
  <int> <chr>            
1     1 particular word  
2     2 particular word  
3     2 word phrase      
4     2 phrase particular
```

Finally, `count` the bigrams like so:

```
## earlier steps (see above) 
## ... |>
count(tokens)
```

```
+ # A tibble: 3 x 2
# Rowwise: 
  tokens                n
  <chr>             <int>
1 particular word       2
2 phrase particular     1
3 word phrase           1
```

Comment: The final output should have 'particular word' = 2 which would be 1x for ID 1 and 1x for ID 2, 'word phrase'  = 1, 'phrase particular' = 1. This way if an ID has the same phrase repeated, the final count is not getting overinflated.

Comment: Sorry, missed that one. See edit please.

Comment: @ I_O Thank you. Do the |> represent a pipe which would be %>%?

Comment: Also, do I need to filter out punctuation and remove all caps? If so, would I need to do that in the mutate function?

Comment: Yes, the `|>` is the native R pipe which came after the `%>%` tidyverse pipe. You sure can use the latter, though.

Comment: About preprocessing (punctuation, capitalisation, stemming etc.), it probably depends on you ambition and some trial & error (see https://www.tidytextmining.com/tidytext.html ). You might also want to check other packages (e.g. {tm}). I've never done serious textmining so far ;-)